# datastax graphloader performance , is it Bulk loading or using api graph.addVertex for each vertex?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

How can I do Bulk loading into dse graph ?

graph.addVertex is only for one vertex.

I don't understand How "batch_size" config works in the graphLoader.

How graphLoader creates transactions?

Answer (score -1):

sara, you've asked several questions about loading over the past couple of days.  To help with your overall goals, it's recommended to reach out to DataStax to engage with one of our PreSales or Consulting team members as well as reach out to the community via Slack to provide a more iterative response channel compared to SO.  https://academy.datastax.com/slack